# When I save edmx, all templates are transformed automatically. How to stop this behavior in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in, t4

This takes relatively long time to save edmx.

Any help will be appreciated.

Btw, I do not know if this is behavior added to studio by some add-in!

Answer (score 1):

There is a property, on *ConceptualEntityModel*'s properties, called *Transform Related Text Templates On Save*.
(Right click on empty surface on designer and click on properties)

I just had to make it False!